# Fast refresh on left join side table takes so times

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

There is a materialized view:

```
create materialized view mat_report
refresh fast on commit
as
    select 
         o.rowid as post_rowid,
         o.id,
         vp.rowid as valid_post_rowid,
         ivp.rowid as invalid_post_rowid
     from post o, valid_post vp, invalid_post ivp
    where o.code like (vp.code || '%')
      and o.code not like (ivp.code || '%')
      and vp.user_id = ivp.user_id(+)
```

and the log for detection their change as follow:

```
create materialized view log on post  with rowid;

create materialized view log on valid_post with rowid;

create materialized view log on invalid_post with rowid;
```

As you can see the `post` table has inner join with both `valid_post` and `invalid_post`  and `valid_post` has left join with `invalid_post`.

When it is inserted a record into `valid_post`, refreshing of the materialized view is fast and takes less than 3 seconds, but when it is inserted a record into `invalid_post`, it is so slow and takes more than 4 minutes.

Where is it wrong and what do i do?

NOTE: it may be good to mention that I have found some sites where it is focused on `_mv_refresh_use_stats` but unfortunately I could not get it completely.

Comment: What work do you think Oracle has to do when you insert a row into the outer-joined table? Compared to what it has to do for an insert to one of the other tables? Think about how much data has to re re-evaluated in each case.

Comment: what do you mean, would you explain in detail?

Comment: @ Alex Poole  When i insert a record into invalid-table, the related post and its children are not shown

Comment: Are there no solution? is it possible. please help me

Comment: Please don't [cross post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215449/fast-refresh-on-left-join-side-table-takes-so-times).